# Should I switch to a vertical exhaust fan to avoid 90 degree bends?

Tags: hvac, exhaust-fan

I am replacing the original kitchen exhaust fan on my 1950s house.  The old one vented sideways to an immediate 90-degree bend (to 8-inch rigid ducting) and then straight up about 24~36 inches to the roof cap.

[image: Existing and new]

I purchased a [new unit](https://www.broan.com/Bath-Vent-Fan/Utility-Fans/Wall-Ceiling-Mount-Side-Discharge/503) with the same sideways exhaust but after reading some interwebs resources ([for example](https://www.askthebuilder.com/kitchen-exhaust-fan/)) it sounds like avoiding 90-degree bends is best practice.  I didn't see anything in the new unit's installation instructions about 90-degree bends or really any kind of ducting recommendations.

If I were to switch to a [unit with a vertical vent](https://www.broan.com/Bath-Vent-Fan/Utility-Fans/Vertical-Discharge/505) I would need to make up the displacement by using flexible ducting instead of rigid, which I hear is also non-ideal.  (Unless there are bends available at less than 90 degrees for 8-inch ducting; didn't see any at HomeD.)

[image: Proposed vertical]

Which would be the best solution?  Or is there a better one yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See sketch below.

A possibility of using a *adjustable* 90° fitting would do you right in this scenario and you could get the identical roof pitch in that fitting. So this would be a compromise, being *less* than that stated "stay away from 90 bends".

These would let you make an angle equal to your roof's pitch. 0° to 90°

[image: sketch showing vertical flue bending towards roof with adjustable bend]

Comment: Note that depending on where the roof vent actually is, a single bend may not be enough to reach it.

Comment: I actually just bought two of those adjustable fittings last night -- had no idea they existed (though that's not saying much).  They may just do the trick!

Comment: This is a much better solution than the original even. Bends and elbows are pressure drops, the less of either the better but 90 << 30 in term of impact.

Answer (score 1):

Redoing the roof penetration is a considerable hassle. I would stick with the current route.

Comment: I don't think either would require redoing the roof penetration -- just the ducting running from the exhaust unit to the roof.

Comment: I agree with Jim. Your fan's probably about 210 CFM and you won't loose much with a 24 to 36 inch run.

Comment: My fault, for some reason when I looked at the diagram I thought it indicated that the roof penetration was to be moved.

Answer (score 1):

Your "vertical" diagram actually appears to show *two* 90° elbows.  It would be much better with two 45° elbows, and searching for "8 ducting 45 degree elbow" finds lots of hits.

The other important question is "what does the ducting *inside* the HVAC unit look like?"  My guess is that internally there is a duct going vertically or horizontally, and to get an outlet in the other direction, they add a 90° elbow.  If the elbow gets added to create a vertical outlet, there's no point.

Certainly two gentle bends are better than a sharp bends, and smooth interiors are better than corrugated - but it's not that critical unless you are planning on long runs (and your diagram appears to show a short run).

I would just use whatever is most convenient to install.

Comment: Yeah, my MS Paint skills aren't what they used to be -- the ~8 inch delta is more important to the drawing.  And I agree that it doesn't make sense to use a side-vented unit just to add an elbow to make it vent vertically, but it's certainly a bigger operation to fit new ducting and exchange the (special-ordered) unit for a new (special-order) one.  I'm between getting it done quickly and getting it done best.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't see anything in the new unit's installation instructions about 90-degree bends or really any kind of ducting recommendations.

Figures 1 thru 4 in your installation instructions **are** the ducting recommendations from the manufacturer. They show 90° bends...